# Should I be using keyword "this" in a constructor when no arguments are being passed?

Tags: java, constructor, coding-style, this

I was wondering whether I should be using "this" in Java when no arguments are being passed in the constructor of a class.

```
private int id;

public ClassName() {
    this.id = -1;
}
```

OR

```
 private int id;

public ClassName() {
    id = -1;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: We use this to differentiate between class variable and local variable, but as there is no local variable both will work same.

Comment: From a semantical point of view, there's no difference. This is a matter of style and you should ask your colleagues if there's a style guide that you should follow. If not, make up your mind on which variant looks more readable to you, and be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no argument, then it's all the same.
However it's always a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

No, `this` in this case is optional. Only need it when the constructor is passed a parameter named `id` to avoid variable shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing either actually. You should initize that variable in the declaration.

If you have a more complex case, the principle of least redundancy applies: don't write it where it isn't required.

Comment: There might be other constructors that *do* take the id as argument. In that case I wouldn't say it's appropriate to initialize it at the declaration.

Comment: @aioobe then the no-arg constructor should invoke the constructor with arg using `this(-1);`

Comment: Exactly. (And as I said, the initialization should not be done at the declaration.)